# A strategy-proof method of finding the time complexity of complex algorithms?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o

I have a question in regard to time complexity (big-O) in Python. I want to understand the general method I would need to implement when trying to find the big-O of a complex algorithm. I have understood the reasoning behind calculating the time complexity of simple algorithms, such as a for loop iterating over a list of n elements having a O(n), or having two nested for loops each iterating over 2 lists of n elements each having a big-O of n**2. But, for more complex algorithms that implement multiple if-elif-else statements coupled with for loops, I would want to see if there is a strategy to, simply based on the code, in an iterative fashion, to determine the big-O of my code using simple heuristics (such as, ignoring constant time complexity if statements or always squaring the n upon going over a for loop, or doing something specific when encountering an else statement).

I have created a battleship game, for which I would like to find the time complexity, using such an aforementioned strategy.

```py
from random import randint

class Battle:
    def __init__(self):

        self.my_grid = [[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]]

    def putting_ship(self,x,y):
        breaker = False
        while breaker == False:
            r1=x
            r2=y
            element = self.my_grid[r1][r2]

            if element == True:
                continue
            else:
                self.my_grid[r1][r2] = True
                break


    def printing_grid(self):
        return self.my_grid


    def striking(self,r1,r2):

        element = self.my_grid[r1][r2]
        if element == True:
            print("STRIKE!")
            self.my_grid[r1][r2] = False
            return True
        elif element == False:
            print("Miss")
            return False


def game():
    battle_1 = Battle()
    battle_2 = Battle()

    score_player1 = 0
    score_player2 = 0
    turns = 5

    counter_ships = 2

    while True:
        input_x_player_1 = input("give x coordinate for the ship, player 1\n")
        input_y_player_1 = input("give y coordinate for the ship, player 1\n")

        battle_1.putting_ship(int(input_x_player_1),int(input_y_player_1))



        input_x_player_2 = randint(0,9)
        input_y_player_2 = randint(0,9)


        battle_2.putting_ship(int(input_x_player_2),int(input_y_player_2))

        counter_ships -= 1
        if counter_ships == 0:
            break


    while True:
        input_x_player_1 = input("give x coordinate for the ship\n")
        input_y_player_1 = input("give y coordinate for the ship\n")

        my_var = battle_1.striking(int(input_x_player_1),int(input_y_player_1))

        if  my_var == True:
            score_player1 += 1
            print(score_player1)


        input_x_player_2 = randint(0,9)
        input_y_player_2 = randint(0,9)


        my_var_2 = battle_2.striking(int(input_x_player_2),int(input_y_player_2))

        if  my_var_2 == True:
            score_player2 += 1
            print(score_player2)

        counter_ships -= 1
        if counter_ships == 0:
            break


    print("the score for player 1 is",score_player1)
    print("the score for player 2 is",score_player2)





print(game())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just nested `for` loops and `if`/`else` statements, you can take the approach ibonyun has suggested - assume all if/else cases are covered and look at the deepest loops (being aware that some operations like sorting, or copying an array, might hide loops of their own.)

However, your code also has `while` loops. In this particular example it's not too hard to replace them with `for`s, but for code containing nontrivial `while`s there is no general strategy that will always give you the complexity - this is a consequence of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

For example:

```
def collatz(n):
    n = int(abs(n))
    steps = 0
    while n != 1:
        if n%2 == 1:
            n=3*n+1
        else:
            n=n//2
        steps += 1
        print(n)
    print("Finished in",steps,"steps!")
```

So far nobody has been able to prove that this will even *finish* for all n, let alone shown an upper bound to the run-time.

Side note: instead of the screen-breaking

```
self.my_grid = [[False,False,...False],[False,False,...,False],...,[False,False,...False]]
```

consider something like:

```
grid_size = 10
self.my_grid = [[False for i in range(grid_size)] for j in range(grid_size)]
```

which is easier to read and check.

Answer (score 0):

Empirical:
You could do some time trials while increasing *n* (so maybe increasing the board size?) and plot the resulting data. You could tell by the curve/slope of the line what the time complexity is.

Theoretical:
Parse the script and keep track of the biggest O() you find for any given line or function call. Any sorting operations will give you nlogn. A for loop inside a for loop will give you n^2 (assuming their both iterating over the input data), etc. Time complexity is about the broad strokes. O(n) and O(n*3) are both linear time, and that's what really matters.  I don't think you need to worry about the minutia of all your if-elif-else logic. Maybe just focus on worst case scenario?